# Changing FirefoxProfile() preferences more than once using Selenium/Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to download multiple excel links to different file paths depending on the link using Selenium.

I am able to set up the FirefoxProfile to download all links to a certain single path, but I can't change the path on the fly as I try to download different files into different file paths. Does anyone have a fix for this?

> self.fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
> self.ft.set_preferences("browser.download.folderList", 2)
> self.ft.set_preferences("browser.download.showWhenStarting", 2)
> self.ft.set_preferences("browser.download.dir", "C:\SOURCE FILES\BACKHAUL")
> self.ft.set_preferences("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", ("application/vnd.ms-excel))
>
> self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = self.fp)

This code will set the path I want once. But I want to be able to set it multiple times while running one script.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and Mac you can set the profile preferences to download to a directory that is a symbolic link to another directory. Then, while running the Selenium driver, you can change the destination of the symlink to the directory you want to download a file in, using the `os` library in Python.

Code outline (without `try/except` etc):

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER = "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver"

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/your/symlink/name")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "your/mime/type")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, executable_path=DRIVER)

# delete symlink before changing to prevent a FileExistsError when changing the link
if os.path.exists("/your/symlink/name"):
    os.unlink("/your/symlink/name")
# actually change/create the link
os.symlink("/real/target/directory", "/your/symlink/name")
# download the file
driver.get("https://example.com/file")

# set new target directory
os.unlink("/your/symlink/name")
os.symlink("/different/target/directory", "/your/symlink/name")
driver.get("https://example.com/otherfile")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define it only while initializing driver. So to do it with a new path you should `driver.quit` and start it again.

Comment: So I have tried that before, but I get the error : "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\usrujy\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpckcz20\\cert8.db'. The files are then downloaded to my downloads directory (not what I specified).